# How to check if two elements are in an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a function that checks if a key ( a number ) exists in an object, and then if that element has a specific sub element. this is what I am doing

```
const blacklistedCities = {
    [NATION_ID_USA]: [
        'New York',
    ],
    [NATION_ID_JAPAN]: [
        'Tokio',
        'Kyoto',
    ]
}

export function isBlacklistedCity(city, nationId) {
    if(blacklistedCities.indexOf(nationId) !== -1 && blacklistedCities. ??WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE??) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

NATION_ID_USA and NATION_ID_JAPAN are constants imported from another file

this function should return false when the element is found because I am using it from a filter() function somewhere else but I am open to any suggestion

thanks

Comment: Objects don't have an `.indexOf()` method.

Comment: thanks, what should I use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd think of the input object as describing a much simpler array of scalar values that will be queried.

```js
// Convert the input to a set containing [ 'nationId-cityId', ...]
//
const blacklistedCities = {
    NATION_ID_USA: [
        'New York',
    ],
    NATION_ID_JAPAN: [
        'Tokio',
        'Kyoto',
    ]
}

const keys = Object.entries(blacklistedCities).reduce((acc, [nationId, cityIdArray]) => {
  let nationIds = cityIdArray.map(cityId => `${nationId}-${cityId}`)
  acc = acc.concat(nationIds)
  return acc
}, [])

// keep this set around for queries
const queryMe = new Set(keys)

// and query with nation, key pair
function queryFor(nationId, cityId) {
  return queryMe.has(`${nationId}-${cityId}`)
}

console.log(queryFor('NATION_ID_USA', 'New York')) // -> true
console.log(queryFor('NATION_ID_FRANCE', 'Paris')) // -> false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nation name as a property name to index directly into the object, and then use `.includes()` on the array (if present):

```
export function isBlacklistedCity(city, nationId) {
    return (nationId in blacklistedCitites) && blacklistedCities[nationId].includes(city);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this

```js
const blacklistedCities = {
    NATION_ID_USA: [
        'New York',
    ],
    NATION_ID_JAPAN: [
        'Tokio',
        'Kyoto',
    ]
}

function isBlacklistedCity(city, nationId) {
    if(blacklistedCities[nationId] && blacklistedCities[nationId].length > 0 && blacklistedCities[nationId].find((cityInObj) => cityInObj==city)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

console.log(isBlacklistedCity("Tokio", "NATION_ID_JAPAN"));
```